# Why is plm not changing the method? (R)

Tags: r, plm

I can provide code and more information if needed, but the question is the same. Running things like

`plm(formula, data=panel_df, method='anything') %>% summary()`

will only yield information as if I chose `within` as the method. This does not appear to be restricted to a particular panel data frame, though I have only checked with a couple.

Why might this be happening, and what, short of reinstalling R and RStudio, can I do to fix it? I think it was working up to a few days ago, though I am new to `plm`, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be very hard to diagnose your problem without your formula or your data. Consider providing both, using `dput(panel_df)`. In the meantime, what happens if you try one of the examples from `plm`? Like `data(Grunfeld)` followed by `plm(inv~value+capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "random") %>% summary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `method` argument to `plm`. Likely, you want the `model` argument (and in the case of a specific method for the random effect models, `random.method`). Please have a look at the documentation; the vignettes can serve as a particular good introduction.

Building upton your code, these examples should work:

```
plm(formula, data=panel_df, model='within') %>% summary()
plm(formula, data=panel_df, model='random') %>% summary()
plm(formula, data=panel_df, model='pooling') %>% summary()
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't reading closely enough in the documentation. Thanks!